# Windows hangs when processing an exception in debug mode

Tags: debugging, exception, driver, break

I am creating an "Kernel Anti-Debugging Driver".

int 3 / int 2d instruction is in debug mode, Windows hangs until the debugger is connected.

I would like to implement it so that it does not stop if the kernel debugger does not exist at the time of the call.

Thank you for your answer :D.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/determining-if-a-debugger-is-attached

Comment: great! thank you :D